# Django : how to give user/group permission to view model instances for a specified period of time

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-authentication, django-permissions

I am fairly new to Django and could not figure out by reading the docs or by looking at existing questions. I looked into Django permissions and authentication but could not find a solution.

Let's say I have a Detail View listing all instances of a Model called *Item*. For each *Item*, I want to control which *User* can view it, and for **how long**. In other words, for each *User* having access to the *Item*, I want the right/permission to view it to **expire** after a specified period of time. After that period of time, the *Item* would disapear from the list and the *User* could not access the url detailing the *Item*.

The logic to implement is pretty simple, I know, but the "per user / per object" part confuses me. Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Information about UserItemExpiryDate has to be stored in a separate table (Model). I would recommend using your coding in Django.

There are few scenarios to consider: 
1) A new user is created, and he/she should have access to items. 
In this case, you add entries to UserItemExpiry with new User<>Item combination (as key) and expiry date. Then, for logged in user you look for items from Items that has User<>Item in UserItemExpiry in the future. 
2) A new item is created, and it has to be added to existing users. 
In such case, you add entries to UserItemExpiry with ALL users<> new Item combination (as key) and expiry date. And logic for "selecting" valid items is the same as in point 1.

Best of luck, 
Radek Szwarc